# Enabling boto3 sending SES on ECS instance without using IAM access key / secret

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-iam

I have an ECS task that I'd like to be able to send email with SES. My plan is to use a library like `boto3` for Python.

I could create an IAM user with access key/secret pair and inject this into the task container definition, but is there a way to do this with pure policies, or some type of assume-role?

I know that `boto3` requires either env vars or a configuration file, so I'm not sure how exactly I'd enable that or if this is possible. Just trying to learn more the limits of the AWS IAM architecture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a role and assign it to ECS task.

Refer: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_IAM_role.html

Comment: how does boto get the credentials though ?

Comment: @lollercoaster: boto3 will find out from list of possible locations. => https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/configuration.html

Comment: 8th item, you're right! wow can't believe I didn't know this.